# Making a tar file by date

Tags: linux, find, tar, linux-mint

Hi I'm with a simple question but didn't find why it's happenig,

I want to make a tar only with the files that downloaded yesterday.
I'm using *find* to take all the file names, but when I try to use *tar* with *find* to make a tar, it make a file tar with all the items in the directory.
Let me give an exemple:

When I run a
`find -mtime 0` it gives me some files that I downloaded yesterday

```
./linuxmint-19-xfce-32bit.iso
./utserver.tar.gz
./nf_9866.pdf
./-@ut c4d 22.torrent
```

But when i use `find -mtime 0 | xargs tar -zcvf teste.tar.gz -T -` It makes the tar with all the files

```
./Modelo_KCS_-_Devolucao_de_Compra2.doc
./Modelo_KCS_-_Devolucao_de_Compra2(2).doc
./Pref.25-04-20231-3.pdf
./Centro_Diag.14-04-20231.pdf
./OC 2290.pdf
./Configuracao_Cliente.docx
./Twine.html
./empresa.ods
./file22.xlsx
[...]
```

What I'm doing wrong?

I tried different ways to get files by date like `

```
find  -newermt 2023-06-30 ! -newermt 2023-07-01 | xargs tar -cvzf teste.tar.gz
find /home/user/Downloads/ -type f -newermt 2023-06-29 ! -newermt 2023-06-30 | tar -czvf teste.tar.gz`
```

but neither ways worked.

Comment: probably not the cause of your issue, but you should use null character delimiting with `find .... -print0` and `xargs -0 ...`  so that whitespace in file names doesn't gum up the works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `xargs` when `tar` already reads the filenames from *stdin*. This should work to create a tarball with your downloads from yesterday:

```
find . -type f -mtime 1 | tar czvf test.tar.gz -T -
```

If you still experience issues it's most likely an incorrect find result.
What happens if you try the same but with a filename wildcard:

```
find . -name '*.docx' | tar czvf alldocs.tar.gz -T -
```

You can also do this in two steps where you can verify your list:

```
find . -mtime 1 > /tmp/list.txt
tar czvf test.tar.gz -T /tmp/list.txt
```

If there is anything in your tarball that wasn't in `/tmp/list.txt` then use the contents of the list as arguments:

```
cat /tmp/list.txt|xargs tar czvf test.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thanks dude, it helped me a lot. I just add a `xargs basemane -a` in the command line to create the tar file without a dir named . inside of it. It became something like 
`find . -type f -mtime 0 | xargs basename -a | tar czvf bck-`date +%d-%m-%y`.tar.gz -T -`